# Creating an strlen function in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, strlen

the mission is to create a function that replaces strlen but in the order I'll present you'd have to fill the empty spots. I tried something but got stuck where I need to count the size and return it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLENGTH 80

int my_strlen(char* s)
{
    char *p = (1);
    while (2)
        (3);

    return (4);
}


int main()
{

    char str[MAXLENGTH];
    int len;
    printf("Enter a string:");
    gets(str);
    len = my_strlen(str);
    printf("The length of the string %s is %d\n", str, len);
}
```

I tried this but got stuck at 3, how to count the size

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLENGTH 80

int my_strlen(char* s)
{
    char *p = s;
    while (*p++ != '\0')
        (3);

    return (4);
}


int main()
{

    char str[MAXLENGTH];
    int len;
    printf("Enter a string:");
    gets(str);
    len = my_strlen(str);
    printf("The length of the string %s is %d\n", str, len);
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are encountering? What have you tried so far?

Comment: So what is your actual question? What specifically prevents you from completing or even starting the task?

Comment: To answer your question though, `char *p = s; while (*p != '\0') p++; return p - s;`.

Comment: If it's supposed to replace `strlen` it should return `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t mystrlen(const char *restrict s)
{
    const char *restrict e = s;
    while(*e) e++;

    return (uintptr_t)e - (uintptr_t)s;
}
```

But I would not advice to show it your teacher.....

Answer (score -1):

I've just replaced your `(3)` and `(4)` with `i++` that will increment until termination **(\0)** and will return `(i)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLENGTH 80

int my_strlen(char* s)
{
    int i=1;
    char *p = s;
    while (*p++)
        i++;

    return (i);
}


int main()
{

    char str[MAXLENGTH];
    int len;
    printf("Enter a string:");
    gets(str);
    len = my_strlen(str);
    printf("The length of the string %s is %d\n", str, len);
}
```

returning value will be **+1** (including \0)

Comment: Do not use `gets`, it is no longer part of the standard, and `size_t` is a better option when counting characters.

Comment: Why would you return the length *plus one*? That makes absolutely no sense at all. The `strlen` manual explicitly states *without* the terminating `\0`.